# Poison.Encoder exception in Phoenix app

Tags: node.js, elixir, phoenix-framework, axios

I have a phoenix app secured using guardian and Uberauth which receives posts from a node app (GraphQL server). It is secured by passing a JWT in the authorization header.

The authorization seems to be working fine, however in my Phoenix controller, it is blowing up with

`** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Poison.Encoder.BitString.chunk_size/3
(poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:127: Poison.Encoder.BitString.chunk_size(<<5, 230, 171, 122, 183, 178, 38, 22, 198, 114, 35, 162, 36, 133, 51, 83, 19, 34, 34, 194, 39, 71, 151, 2, 35, 162, 36, 165, 117, 66, 39, 13::size(4)>>, nil, 0)`

Before I added authentication, this was working correctly. Stranger still, a curl request, like follows:

`curl -i -H "authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJVc2VyOjIiLCJleHAiOjE0OTU2MjU3MjEsImlhdCI6MTQ2NDA4OTcyMSwiaXNzIjoiU2hvcHNoYXJlIiwianRpIjoiMDE2OTJjMzctM2QxYi00Yzc5LThiMjYtYzExN2QyNTM1MGI5IiwicGVtIjp7fSwic3ViIjoiVXNlcjoyIiwidHlwIjoidG9rZW4ifQ.GfqVSw3hPsy-zOp1yx6IXAGhM4uX0CsMbU3DHqtFCn7SQYPi24DJ2F4yC48cfiQi82-hvpUoxdnFm_x5osBb3w" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"comment": {"content": "test"}}' http://localhost:8081/api/v1/current_user/products/1/comments`

Works 100% correctly, as expected!

My outgoing Axios request looks like:

`frontend_1  | { headers: 
frontend_1  |    { authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJVc2VyOjIiLCJleHAiOjE0OTU3OTg4OTUsImlhdCI6MTQ2NDI2Mjg5NSwiaXNzIjoiU2hvcHNoYXJlIiwianRpIjoiYWE2YTE2M2YtYzM5ZC00ODVjLTgwMjEtMDMxMjUwNzc4YjcxIiwicGVtIjp7fSwic3ViIjoiVXNlcjoyIiwidHlwIjoidG9rZW4ifQ.4vosfEx69s_90UlCkgWNbxoNNAKuckYvqNRsqfznvzddI-k63LaXz7MWum82aSiHDkiw7L3tk6df8tZVh2Zz_A',
frontend_1  |      Accept: 'application/json',
frontend_1  |      'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
frontend_1  |   timeout: 0,
frontend_1  |   transformRequest: [ [Function: transformResponseJSON] ],
frontend_1  |   transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponseJSON] ],
frontend_1  |   method: 'post',
frontend_1  |   url: 'http://api:8080/api/v1/current_user/products/2/comments',
frontend_1  |   data: { comment: { content: 'test' } },
frontend_1  |   withCredentials: undefined }`

**I'm at a bit of a lost of what to try next. It seems that no matter what I send in the payload, the char list in Elixir seems to stay the same. I can't seem to decode what is in that char list either which I suspect is a clue to what's going on.**

Comment: I realize that you mentioned that the code was working before you added authentication but it's still really hard to say what might be going on here without code.  Can you share your code please?

Comment: Like most problems, I just needed to sleep on it and think about it again the next day before realising what was wrong. Thanks for the reply though :)

Answer (score 0):

At some point I'd decided to prefix the auth token with `Bearer`, however I wasn't using any roles in Guardian when I created the tokens. When Guardian tried to read the token I sent back it was causing an error.